# Phabricator users "submit" review feedback functionality in Bitbucket?

Tags: bitbucket, phabricator

We have users on Phabricator who are being migrated over to Bitbucket.

They have come to prefer the following behavior:

The engineer who created a pull request would not be notified of any review feedback until the reviewer performs "submit" or "publish".  This allows the reviewer the time to write and revise their feedback as they read the code and begin to understand the entirety of the change set.

In the Bitbucket world, the reviewer's feedback gets sent (by default) as soon as he or she hits "Comment" the change set/pull request creator gets notified.

Is it possible, via plugin or settings change, to get Bitbucket to hold off on the notification bit until the reviewer is ready?

Comment: Bitbucket Cloud or Bitbucket Server?

Comment: Bitbucket Server